# how to remove the title of the iframe in bot framework web chat

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I got the iFrame for my bot that uses Microsoft bot framework by registering the bot with them. Now, I need to remove/change the title of that bot from "chat" to another custom one.

How can I do this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to remove/change the title of that bot from "chat" to another custom one

To redesign and customize web chat interface, you can try to clone [the repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), modify the source code, and compile into your own version. To achieve your requirement: changing the title of web chat, you can find and modify the following code snippet in **Chat.tsx**.

```
<div className="wc-header">
    <span>{ typeof state.format.chatTitle === 'string' ? state.format.chatTitle : state.format.strings.title }</span>
</div>
```

Simply modify it with below code and compile it:

```
<span>{ typeof state.format.chatTitle === 'string' ? "my chat bot" : "my chat bot" }</span>
```

Use it in my website, which works for me.

[image]

Comment: Or edit the string permanently in [Strings.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Strings.ts#L25)

Comment: Hi @BhashithaHemantha, any updates? do you try my approach to customize web chat interface? it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to edit the title when you use the iFrame without 'hacks' like modifying the DOM with CSS overrides. However you don't have to edit / fork the WebChat code itself, as proposed in other answers. It is possible to pass a custom title / empty title using [ChatProps](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/875).

Have a look at the possibilities to [include the WebChat on your own website](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline). Then pass the `chatTitle` parameter to change the title to your preference.

> Rules for chatTitle:
>
> - undefined or true is passed, we will show the header with default text (locale-sensitive)
> - false (or falsy except undefined) is passed, we will remove the header
> - a string is passed, we will show the header with the text

Comment: Good to know. Do you know if the pull request you mentioned is available yet in the version of the webchat hosted on the CDN?

Comment: Good point! It looks like it will be part of the v0.12.0 release which is still [stated as prerelease](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/releases). For the time being you need to compile the source code yourself, until v0.12.0 is published on the CDN.